# Unable to unserialize value error when customer data is not display on editing the details?

Tags: admin, customer, magento2.2.2, unserialize

Getting error:

> Unable to unserialize value

[image]

```
vendor/magento/framework/serialize/json.php
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if your database has any serialized values, magento2.2.x does not support serialise/unserialize data, convert to json array.

Check `customer_eav_attribute` table for null values.
`` select * from `customer_eav_attribute` where (`validate_rules` =''); ``

Query ran to resolve the issue:

`` UPDATE `customer_eav_attribute` SET validate_rules='[]' where (`validate_rules` =''); ``